# shp2pgsql not found on PostGis Docker container

Tags: postgis

I deployed Postgis 13-3.4 [from this site](https://registry.hub.docker.com/r/postgis/postgis/)  , now I want to import Spatial data as described [here](https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/loading_data.html) but command

```
shp2pgsql -D -I -s 26918 /tmp/nyc_census_blocks_2000.shp nyc_census_blocks_2000.shp > /tmp/pp.sql
```

doesn't work , it seam the command is not available on /usr/bin
( I copied the .shp, .shx, .prj and .dbf in /tmp

where I got wrong ?